# "exports is not defined" error after upgrading Storybook to v7.6.x

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook

I tried upgrading Storybook from v7.5.3 to its latest version (at the time of posting this question, v7.6.7).

Our solution uses Webpack5 and it's written in TypeScript/ReactJS.

The solution builds just fine and I can't see any errors whilst Storybook is loading, but for any story the error below is presented:

```
exports is not defined
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at ./src/components/unread-indicator/UnreadIndicator.stories.tsx (http://localhost:6006/components-unread-indicator-UnreadIndicator-stories.iframe.bundle.js:27:1)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:681:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:338:21)
    at http://localhost:6006/main.iframe.bundle.js:1880:10
    at async importFn (http://localhost:6006/main.iframe.bundle.js:150:27)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async StoryStore.loadEntry (http://localhost:6006/sb-preview/runtime.js:47:11053)
    at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
    at async PreviewWeb.onPreloadStories (http://localhost:6006/sb-preview/runtime.js:101:1662)
```

This is an example of a story:

```
import { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';

import UnreadIndicator from './UnreadIndicator';

const meta: Meta<typeof UnreadIndicator> = {
    component: UnreadIndicator,
    title: 'Components/UnreadIndicator',
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof UnreadIndicator>;

export const Default: Story = {};
```

And its related component:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { memo } from 'react';

import styles from './UnreadIndicator.less';

function UnreadIndicator({
    className,
    'data-testid': testId = 'UnreadIndicator',
}: {
    className?: string;
    'data-testid'?: string;
}) {
    return (
        <div
            className={classNames(styles.root, className)}
            data-testid={testId}
        />
    );
}

export default memo(UnreadIndicator);
```

What could be causing the breakage?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get over the issue by making some changes to the solution `tsconfig`.

The changes were to the `module` and `moduleResolution` values, under `compilerOptions`. I changed the `module` value from `NodeNext` to `ESNext`. Also, as the `moduleResolution` with a value of `NodeNext` raised a mismatch issue, I changed its value to `Bundler`.

Before:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "NodeNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext
    },
}
```

After:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    },
}
```